# Open firewall between IBM MQ to AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, websphere, ibm-mq, firewall, aws-msk

I have a use case where data is populating from IBM MQ(Source) and trying to connect AWS MSK cluster. I created AWS cluster and I have the IBM MQ config details to create a connector. I wanted to open a secure firewall between AWS and IBM MQ.

Can some one please help me here how to open a secure firewall in between.?

Comment: This might be better asked at https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @dbc . will post there